# Where is storefront home page content

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

I just started to do a small project on storefront theme and I am able to remove, reorder homepage sections but I am trying to find where the actual functions located

would someone guide me where I can find the actual function for example storefront_homepage_content

Answer (score 1):

1st you go to WordPress dashboard then see left sidebar and find setting tab then mouse hover on setting and click on reading.
now select a static page radio button then see your home page name.that name is your page name.
now go to pages and find same name page and click on edit.
now you able to change to your home page section.